# Yet or Although?

Tags: conjunctions

> The new service was expected to be a success; ____very few
>   customers upgraded their accounts.
>   **A. yet**
>    B. just
>    C. moreover
>  
>   D. although

In this sentence, I am confused between “yet” and "although". I think **although** is more correct, but the answer is **yet**. Please help me make clear about the usage of **yet**. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Each of these words mean different, and would totally change the meaning of the sentence.
The correct answer is "**Yet**" because it's the only word that would provide the exact meaning.

Here, the sentence means that some new service upgrade was introduced, to lets say some bank accounts, and was expected to be successful ***but*** few people used it (so it did not come out as successful as the producers thought it would). So, **yet** would fit here.

**Although** would change the meaning in the context that few people upgraded their accounts, ***still*** the producers expected the service to be a success.
*OR* ***Despite the fact that*** few people upgraded their accounts, the producers expected the service to be a success

Comment: Notice that although = but (the word that you have highlighted) https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/although

Comment: @RubioRic Here, I think it's using "despite the fact that" definition

Comment: That's not what you have written above, you have used the word "but" to explain the sentence

Comment: @RubioRic Yes, I have clarified that now. Besides, note that I have added the explanation in the brackets.

Comment: Let me quote your second paragraph: "was expected to be successful but few people used it" You have stated that this is the right interpretation of the sentence, then "although" is the right choice and not "yet"

Comment: The main difference between yet and although is simply that **Although** implies that the customers didn't use it, but producers still expect it to be successful. (Users did not use it firstly, but producers are still expecting it).  **Yet** would imply that the expectation came first, and the failure came afterwards.

Comment: I think `yet` is right.  `yet` is more equal to `but` ,  `Although` is different.    `Although` looks like:  you are right, but no one trust you.   `yet` is more like :   no one trust you, but you are right. By my feeling.