# Although vs Yet

Tags: grammar

> The new service was expected to be a success; __________ very few customers upgraded their accounts.

My student chose "**although**" for the blank but "**yet**" is correct. What is the grammatical reason for that?

This is a [TOEIC question](https://www.examenglish.com/TOEIC/toeic_listening_and_reading.htm) from the Reading section (part 5).

Any help with this question is appreciated!

Comment: They are both correct. As would be *however*, *but*, *still*, and *nonetheless*. (I may not have exhausted the possibilities.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford I thought so too but the TOEIC test I took with the student said otherwise. Perhaps the test is wrong? (https://www.examenglish.com/TOEIC/toeic_listening_and_reading.htm Reading Section Part 5 )

Comment: @anna,  if this is from a toeic test, please mention that in the question and link to the source.  You can [edit] your comment into the question.

Comment: @James K Thank you for pointing that out James! Done.

Comment: Duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/201763/yet-or-although ?

Comment: Oh, you're right Smock. Should I delete this question then?

Answer (score 4):

Both are possible.

Some treat "yet" in this position as a coordinating conjunction. As with "but", some people prefer not to start a sentence with a conjunction. This usage is very common and can be construed as linking with the previous context.

Although is also a conjunction, and it also means "but". The use of although tends to introduce an "anti-explanation". It starts a clause that gives a reason why something is not expected.

So I think the hair-splitting that the question is testing is that the "anti-explanation" is the first clause, not the second. Thus the error with "although" is semantic, not grammatical.

> Although the new service was expected to be a success, very few customers upgraded their accounts.

For me, both *although* and *yet* are acceptable. For some people both may be unacceptable for different reasons, and another word like "However," or "Nevertheless," might be prefered.